# ROS Answers SE migration: ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ros-hydro, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just installed ubuntu 13.10- the newest version but I have read that the newest version of ROS is compatible with 12.04. I haven't presonalised linux yet. Is it a good idea to get 12.04? Will it be also compatible with OpenCv?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/92526/ubuntu-13.10/) by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2013-10-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using ROS hydro on Ubuntu 13.10 will require certain Linux skills. If you ask that question, you probably do not have those skills. So you should use an older version of Ubuntu, like 13.04.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wilk](https://answers.ros.org/users/7921/wilk/) on 2013-10-21**:
Ok thanks a lot, I reinstalled 12,04 stable one

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I been running ubuntu 13 and ros hydro with gazebo 1.9 and it works just fine.

---

Originally posted by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) with karma: 713 on 2013-10-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The target platforms for ROS releases are covered in (ROS REP 3](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#hydro-medusa-apr-2013)

The latest release of ROS, Hydro Medusa, supports 12.04 12.10 and 13.04.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1